# Is there a way to find errors in a Gaussian fit?

Tags: statistics, least-squares, gaussian

If I have a set of data that $(x_i,y_i)$ could be visualized on a scatter plot, and I want to apply the least-square method to fit them using a Gaussian function:

$$
G(x) = B+A\exp\left[-\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right]
$$

I think this would give us an estimation of the expected value $\mu$. However, is there a way I can find the error of those 4 parameters $A,B,\mu,\sigma$ using this method?

Comment: What do you mean by *find the error of this method* ?

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Thanks for the comment. I'm assuming there's an 'ideal data' with no errors, with an ideal $\mu$ (we can call that $\mu_i$), but the data I'm fitting is subject to measurement errors, so we can make an estimation of $\mu_i$. I wonder if we could determine the error of this estimation.

Comment: I do not know what is $\mu_i$. In any manner, using ordinary least square method, it is a simple nonlinear regression since you can generate good estimates of $\mu$ and $\sigma$. When done, look at the standard deviations for the parameters, the $R^2$, p-test and so on.

Comment: The displayed formula is not a Gaussian.

Comment: @user10354138 Thanks, just corrected

Comment: In principle, if you assume the "Platonic data" (the true values, but of which one can only perceive the shadows perturbed by measurement errors) follow a Gaussian distribution with some (unknown) mean and standard deviation, and you specify _a priori_ probability distributions for mean, standard deviation, and measurement errors, then you can compute the expected deviation of the value $\sigma$ computed from the measured data and the actual standard deviation. But that is a lot of assumptions, a difficult computation, for a conclusion that no doubt is: the error in the computed error is big.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are modeling your problem traditionally as $Y_i|x_i\sim \mathcal N(\beta_0+\beta_1x_i, \sigma^2)$ which indeed can be visualized on a scatterplot. In this case the MLE's of $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ are the least square estimators ($\hat\beta_1=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(Y_i-\bar Y)(x_i-\bar x)}{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)}$, $\hat\beta_0=\bar Y-\hat\beta_1 \bar x$) and they have MSE (mean squared error) $E(\hat\beta_1-\beta_1)^2=Var(\hat\beta_1)=\sigma^2/s_x^2$ and $E(\hat\beta_0-\beta_0)^2=Var(\hat\beta_0)=\sigma^2\left(\frac 1n+\frac{\bar x^2}{s_x^2}\right)$ where $s_x=(\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)^2)^{\frac 12}$ owing to the fact that they are unbiased estimators.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What does the notation $Y_i|x_i$ mean? In this case, should I add $(̂_1)$ and$(̂_0)$ to obtain the error of $\mu$?

Comment: @IGY Under the simple linear regression model the mean of each $Y_i$ given $x_i$ has 2 parameters, $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$, not just $\mu$

Comment: Can I determine the error of $\mu$ from that?

Comment: @IGY just to be clear, you have data $(x_i, y_i)$ that are on a scatterplot and you want to fit a linear regression right? there is not really a $\mu$ in this context; or by "scatterplot," do you instead mean a one-dimensional plot with only *x*'s that you want to fit a Gaussian density to?

Comment: Thanks, I have data $(_,_)$, and I want to fit them using the Gaussian function above with 4 parameters ($A,B,\mu,\sigma$). I wonder if I could find the error of $\mu$ using this non-linear fit.

Comment: @iGY I do not think it is possible. Least squares is a *method* that takes the minimum squared distances from the curve and spits out optimal values. So you will get values for $A, B, \mu, \sigma$ if you take four partial derivatives of the $Q=\sum(y_i-B+A\exp [-((x-\mu)/\sigma)^2]$ and set them equal to 0 and solve.

In order to have an error you would need to assume some kind of noise $\epsilon$ (usually normal), then the $Y_i$ will have a joint distribution, and  $A, B, \mu, \sigma$ can be estimated, and you can find their expected error $E(A-\hat A)^2$. could be wrong though

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll look up some documentation about that:)